# Call an anonymous function with pipe operator

Tags: r, purrr

I want to apply an anonymous function to a tibble data, for example

```
tb <- tibble(vec1 = 1:10, vec=2)
```

The following code fails

```
tb %>% map(function(x) {x[1,1] + x[2, 1]})
```

but the following works

```
tb %>% {map(list(.), function(x) {x[1,1] + x[1,2]})}
tb %>% map_depth(0, function(x) {x[1,1] + x[1,2]})
```

I am wondering if there are better options than the last two.

Comment: Do you need `tb %>%  reduce(`+`)`.  Not clear what your expected output is `tb %>% map(~ .x[1] + .x[2])`

Comment: What's the point of the pipe if you're using the name of the data frame in the function?

Comment: @Gregor corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @akrun it is just an example. The purpose is to pass tb to the function. It seems the columns of tb are used as the input when using map.

Comment: Also, you have some mismatched `[` and `}` in your failing code.

Comment: That's what map does... iterate over an input. If you give `map` a data frame, it iterates over columns.

Comment: @Gregor So I asked for alternatives for passing tb to an anonymous function that is defined on the step of the 'pipe' flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use anonymous functions directly, wrapped in parentheses:

```
tb %>% (function(x) {x[1,1] + x[2, 1]})
#   vec1
# 1    3
```

Comment: [pryr](https://rdrr.io/cran/pryr/man/f.html) has a more compact anonymous function `f`

Answer (score 6):

Since R version 4.1, R now has a built-in syntax for both the pipe operator (`|>`) and anonymous functions. Calling an anonymous function in a pipe chain can be done like this:

```
mtcars |> (\(.x) plot(.x$hp, .x$mpg))()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few alternatives :

```r
library(tidyverse,mask.ok = TRUE)
tb <- tibble(vec1 = 1:10, vec=2)

tb %>% {function(x) {x[1,1] + x[2, 1]}}()
#>   vec1
#> 1    3
tb %>% exec(function(x) {x[1,1] + x[2, 1]},.)
#>   vec1
#> 1    3
tb %>% as_mapper(~.[1,1] + .[2, 1])()
#>   vec1
#> 1    3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A solution for general anonymous functions with one or more parameters reads

```r
library(dplyr)

tb <- tibble(vec1 = 1:10, vec=2)

tb %>% {function(df, n){
    df$vec3 <- df[, 1]^n
    df
  }
}(2)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>     vec1   vec vec3$vec1
#>    <int> <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1     2         1
#>  2     2     2         4
#>  3     3     2         9
#>  4     4     2        16
#>  5     5     2        25
#>  6     6     2        36
#>  7     7     2        49
#>  8     8     2        64
#>  9     9     2        81
#> 10    10     2       100

tb %>% {function(df, n){
  df[1, n] + df[2, n]
  }
}(1)
#>   vec1
#> 1    3

tb %>% {function(df, n){
  df[1, n] + df[2, n]
}
}(2)
#>   vec
#> 1   4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>